# Bimodules with basepoints

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

I'm interested in bimodules $M$ over $R$ where there is a special point $*\in M$
such that $* \cdot r = r\cdot *$ for all $r\in R$.  Is there a standard name for such gadgets?